# How can i delete last column from my text file

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, text, text-files

I would like to delete the last column from my text file. How can i achieve this.
My text file is TAB delimited.

Input text file looks like:

```
Designator     MAX PN        Footprint         Center-X(mm)   Center-Y(mm)   Location

 "C10"  "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "122.492"   "69.469"     "BOTTOM"
 "DOC1" "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "264.211"   "12.814"     "BOTTOM"
 "C102" "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "251.346"   "11.201"     "BOTTOM"
 "C105" "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"     "0"         "0"     "BOTTOM"
 "PCB"  "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "306.197"   "29.909"      "BOTTOM"
 "C107" "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "273.685"   "29.527"     "BOTTOM"
```

I Want to delete  the entire column called Location from the text file.. and process the output..

Code snippet:

```
  public void do_name()
{
    string[] search_text = new string[] { "PCB", "DOC", "PCB1", "DOC1" };
    string old;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(textBox1.Text))
    {
        while ((old = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (old.Contains(search_text[0]) || old.Contains(search_text[1]) ||
                old.Contains(search_text[2]) || old.Contains(search_text[3]) ||
               old.Split('\t').Contains(@"""0"""))
                continue;
            else
                sb.AppendLine(old);
        }
        sr.Close();
    }
    File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: @D Stanley any idea!!! please.. Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the last column from the line before processing.

```
public void do_name()
{
    bool headerRead = false;
    bool layerColumnPresent = false;
    string[] search_text = new string[] { "PCB", "DOC", "PCB1", "DOC1" };
    string old;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(textBox1.Text))
    {
        while ((old = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (!headerRead)
            {
                layerColumnPresent = old.Substring(old.LastIndexOf("\t").ToLower()).Contains("layer")
                headerRead = true;
            }
            if (old.Length > 0 && layColumnPresent) // if not a zero length string
            {
                old = old.Substring(0, old.LastIndexOf("\t"));
            }
            if (old.Contains(search_text[0]) || old.Contains(search_text[1]) ||
                old.Contains(search_text[2]) || old.Contains(search_text[3]) ||
                old.Split('\t').Contains(@"""0"""))
                continue;
            else
                sb.AppendLine(old);
        }
        sr.Close();
   }
   File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65034/discussion-between-jac-and-stacy-kebler).

Comment: i am sorry about that the o/p was coming perfectly.. the problem was with my mac,, because the quotation's was coming in a different format.. that the reason i was not able to get the o/p.. sorry to make this question so long.. `the double quotes were coming like this for me >>> “0”....... and when i changed to "0" it worked`

Comment: as an extension to this code, i need to trim only my end ciolmn.. when my column name is "Layer"
else i dont need to trim. can u tell me that..

Thanks in advanceas an extension to this code, i need to trim only my end ciolmn.. when my column name is "Layer"
else i dont need to trim. can u tell me that..

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Error 'int' does not contain a definition for 'ToLower' and no extension method 'ToLower' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` shows this error for `'ToLower'`

Comment: also how to check there are 5 columns alteast present to do `  old = old.Substring(0, old.LastIndexOf("\t"));`. Please give that condition too in OR STATEMENT

Comment: if less than 5 columns.. don't do `old = old.Substring(0, old.LastIndexOf("\t"));`

Comment: @StacyKebler fixed the paren grouping in the answer

Comment: yes i did that.. but jac what happens.. if my text file is having last column name as "location" or any.. i mean the last 6 th column.. i need to show a message box for that.. just want to take the 6th column.. please can you give a check condition for 6th column. pleasee.. thanks

Comment: actually paren is here `old.Substring(old.LastIndexOf("\t"))`

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = File.ReadLines(filename)
                .Where(line => !search_text.Any(text => line.Contains(text))) // <-- As requested by CodeCaster 
                .Select(line => String.Join("\t", line.Split('\t').Take(5)));
File.WriteAllLines(newfilename, query);
```

**EDIT**

```
Func<string, string> trim = s => s.Trim('“','”', '"', ' ' );

var query = File.ReadLines(filename)
            .Select(line => line.Split('\t'))
            .Where(parts => !parts.Any(part => search_text.Contains(trim(part))))
            .Where(parts => !parts.Any(part => trim(part) == "0"))
            .Select(parts => String.Join("\t", parts.Take(5)));
```

Comment: I'm sure OP wants to incorporate this in his existing code, so reading and writing the files twice seems a bit overkill.

Comment: @L.B. the existing code already reads the file using a streamreader to exclude certain rows.

Comment: This answer seems to be a suggestion for OP to use, right? When OP adds this code to his existing code, both `File.ReadLines` and the `StreamReader` will read the file. That is unnecessary, it can be done once. Indeed for example by converting OP's `if` to a `Where` on `ReadLines()`.

Comment: @CodeCaster I see, with addition of `where` then no problem.

Comment: @EZI you code worked for me.. but my column header is not getting deleted.. also tell me.. how can i include `string[] search_text = new string[] { "PCB", "DOC", "PCB1", "DOC1" };` and `old.Split('\t').Contains(@"""0"""))` to my search.. so that i need to delete lines with those words.. and `"0"` too.

Comment: @StacyKebler I updated the answer. (BTW: SO removes your real formatting. If you still have problem, put your test file to somewhere else and post the link)

Comment: @EZI you out put is getting like>>> http://pastie.org/9721554  and see my input file here  >>> http://pastie.org/9721557   .. please save this input file in text format.. that's it

Comment: i need to delete the file.. and my output file should come like this.. this is my expected output file...http://pastie.org/9721588#15-17

Comment: @EZI also i noticed some thing wired.. my input text file is having 25 lines. let say.. in that 3 lines should delete... and rest 22 lines should come as out.. but your code is going me out as again 25 lines... i am wondering why?? should delete the highlighted.. lines.. programmatically http://pastie.org/9721557#13,17,25

Comment: @StacyKebler In fact my code produces the output you expect. 1) I forgot the remove my test char '#' form code. it should be `String.Join("\t", ` not `String.Join("#",` 2) You still have 6 headers because there is no tab char between first two column names `Designator<spaces>MAX PN`. Only spaces.

Comment: i already did that.. but the out put is not coming as expected.. i made every thing as tab delimited.. please try this file.. http://pastie.org/9721948#4,6,8,12 in this i have marked which all lines should delete accruing to the code.. but its not happening.. Thanks

Comment: @StacyKebler I updated the answer. Problem is in quotation marks. See, `“` or `”` are not equal to  `"`

Comment: @EZI now output is perfect but a small issue.. i am getting gap while deleting between lines.. which i don't want.. also i cannot replace the original file.. While i am trying to replace the old text. it says. `file is being used by another person`. I want to replace the text file.. with the deleted lines.. without any gaps.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @StacyKebler **1-** I don't understand the *gap* issue **2-** Of course you can't overwrite the original file while in use. Just delete it and rename the output file after your work is done **3-** I think I have spent enough time on this question, good luck.

Comment: @StacyKebler Given your input http://pastie.org/9721948#4,6,8,12 , my code works fine. It seems your input is different than you showed us (like in `but my column header is not getting deleted`) I am tired of debugging your input. Please learn how to debug your code and don't use my answer (as you have many good different answers).

Comment: @EZI i am sorry about that the o/p was coming perfectly.. the problem was with my mac,, because the quotation's was coming in a different format.. that's the reason i was not able to get the o/p.. sorry to make this question so long.. `the double quotes were coming like this for me >>> “0”....... and when i changed to "0" it worked`

Comment: @StacyKebler As I said 10 hours ago :)

Answer (score 0):

A line contains 6 columns, so `old.Split('\t')` returns an array of 6 strings (if the input formatting is consistent).

In your loop you can select the first 5 elements and glue the array back together:

```
string new = string.Join("\t", old.Split('\t').Take(5));
```

Comment: my rows are not fixed.. it may be upto 657 sometimes... and can be 700 some time.. or 40 sometime.. it varies..

Comment: this worked.. but in my loop its giving an  error.. please update ur code with my full answer.. thnaks

Comment: should delete the highlighted.. lines.. programmatically pastie.org/9721557#13,17,25

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\test.txt");
    string[] newLines = lines.Select(l =>
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(l)) // keep the empty rows
        {
            return l.Remove(l.LastIndexOf(' ')).TrimEnd();
        }

        return l;
    }).ToArray();
    File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\newtest.txt", newLines);
```

Comment: your code worked for me.. but.. i have changed `' '` to `"\t"` because my text file is tab delimited. And tell me how can i include `string[] search_text = new string[] { "PCB", "DOC", "PCB1", "DOC1" };` and `old.Split('\t').Contains(@"""0"""))` to my search.. so that i need to delete lines with those words.. and "0" too.