# Delete last column from file with Python

Tags: python, file, csv, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am basically trying to do the same thing as this guy but with Python:
[How can i delete last column from my text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940261/how-can-i-delete-last-column-from-my-text-file)

How can I remove my last column?

I tried to load the text using `numpy.loadtxt` first, and then just ignore the final array but it wouldn't load at all because the last column contains strings, instead of floats.

Comment: It is not. His last column contained floats, not strings. I am getting error because my last column contains strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `numpy.loadtxt` function has a parameter `usecols`. From [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

```
numpy.loadtxt(
    fname,
    dtype=<type 'float'>,
    comments='#',
    delimiter=None,
    converters=None,
    skiprows=0,
    usecols=None,
    unpack=False,
    ndmin=0
)
Load data from a text file.
...
usecols : sequence, optional Which columns to read, with 0 being
    the first. For example, usecols = (1,4,5) will extract the
    2nd, 5th and 6th columns. The default, None, results in all
    columns being read.
```

Of course this presumes you know in advance how many columns are in the file.

For example, given the following file `test.txt`:

```
100 test1
200 test2
300 test3
```

Loading with `numpy.loadtxt("test.txt")` produces this error.

```
$ python -c "import numpy as np;np.loadtxt('test.txt')"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: test1
```

However using the `usecols` parameter works fine:

```
$ python -c "import numpy as np;print np.loadtxt('test.txt', usecols=(0,))"
[ 100.  200.  300.]
```

Comment: Just did that and I'm still getting error: 'TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable'

Comment: I think you must be doing something wrong. I added an example which I used to test and I hope this clarifies. I think you may not be passing a tuple or list to the usecols parameter. Try `usecols=[0,1]`.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. However, I am still getting this error I described above. I only need the 17th column so I wrote 'loadtxt = ("Filename", skiprows=1, delimiter=",", usecols=(17))' . Is that wrong?

Comment: In python a tuple with a single element needs to be followed by a comma, so you should write `usecols=(17,)` or just use a list which doesn't have this problem `usecols=[17]`. You should also know that the 17th column has the column index 16, so maybe you actually need to write `usecols=[16]`.

Comment: Finally! Thank you so much! The comma was missing. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

This code block reads the file as a "String array"

```
numpy.loadtxt('input_file.txt', dtype=str, usecols=(1,2,3,4))
```

where `usecols` is used to specify which columns need to be read into the numpy array.

**output:**

```
array([['MAX', 'Footprint', 'Center-X', 'Center-Y'],
       ['"100-0009"', '"1206', '-', 'CAPACITOR"'],
       ['"100-0009"', '"1206', '-', 'CAPACITOR"'],
       ['"100-0009"', '"1206', '-', 'CAPACITOR"'],
       ['"100-0009"', '"1206', '-', 'CAPACITOR"'],
       ['"100-0009"', '"1206', '-', 'CAPACITOR"'],
       ['"100-0009"', '"1206', '-', 'CAPACITOR"']], 
      dtype='|S10')
```